# Why the $(n+1)$th prime number cannot exceed the smallest prime divisor of $p_1\dotsc p_n + 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime number in its natural order. We want to show that

$$p_{n+1} \leq p_1\dotsc p_n + 1 \tag{1}$$

I know $p_1\dotsc p_n + 1 > 1$, so it has at least one prime divisor, but the text says that $p_{n+1}$ cannot exceed the smallest of these divisors, but I cannot understand why, especially when I imagine $p_{n+1}$ being very large. Although some examples confirm that this statement is true, I cannot make a connection as to why the $n+1$ prime number cannot exceed the smallest prime divisor. Once this has been shown to be true, $(1)$ immediately follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$p_1\cdots p_n+1$ is coprime to each of $p_1,\dots,p_n$, hence it has a prime divisor $p$ which is not one of $p_1,\dots,p_n$.

Since $p_{n+1}$ is by definition the smallest prime greater than $p_n$, it follows that $p_{n+1}\leq p\leq p_1\cdots p_n+1$.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest prime divisor of $p_1p_2\dots p_n+1$ is a prime, since it is a prime it is of the form $p_k$, and we must have $n+1\leq k$. Therefore $p_{n+1}\leq p_k$.

Answer (score 2):

To make this perhaps a little less abstract, consider the number $2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times \cdots \times p_n+1$.  When you divide this number by $2$, it must leave a remainder of $1$.  This is also true if you divide this number by $3$, $5$, $7$, or indeed any prime up to and including $p_n$.  It follows that any prime factor of this number must be greater than $p_n$.

Since there can be no prime number between $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$, any prime factors of this number must be greater than or equal to $p_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Always $\,K\,$ is coprime to $\,K\!-1\,$ since any common divisor divides their difference $ = 1$.

Therefore $\, K = 1+p_1\cdots p_n\,$ and $\,K\!-\!1 = p_1\cdots p_n\,$ have no common prime factors.

But the $\,p_i\,$ are the *first* $\,n\,$ primes, so the prime factors of $\,K\,$ are all $\,\ge p_{n+1}=$ next prime.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the primes $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$ can not be a divisor of $X=\prod_1^np_i+1$ (obvious).

Hence $X=\prod_1^mq_j$ where the smallest  of the primes $q_j$ is greater than

the largest of the primes $p_i$.

Consequently $$p_{n+1}\le q_1\lt q_2\lt...\lt q_m$$